# What are the side effects of changing (almost) all catcodes to letter/other?

Tags: context, verbatim, catcodes, learning

In ConTeXt one can change the catcodes such that (almost) all the special characters print themselves in text mode, while some of them keep their original meaning in math mode (e.g. `_` and `^`).  The corresponding command is `\asciimode`.

```
\asciimode
\starttext

#$%&^_|~  %% these are disabled

\ { }     %% these remain enabled

\stoptext
```

My question is, what would be the side effects in standard LaTeX if there was such a thing, or more specifically, are there macros in standard LaTeX which assume a certain catcode regime?

---

This question is partly inspired by Aditya's nice blog post [Some thoughts on lowering the learning curve for using TeX](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/some-thoughts-on-lowering-the-learning-curve-for-using-tex-part-i/).

Comment: Note that the catcode being used here is not 'letter' but 'other'. Also, do you want to limit the question to LuaTeX or are other engines also involved?

Comment: if you just do that for the body of a document then mostly things should work as you expect and it often makes sense to do that, for example if you have text with a lot of percentage values and no tex comments making `%` a normal character often makes sense.

Comment: @JosephWright I am not sure to what extent the formats differ but I am targeting more towards a user perspective, i.e. would catcode changing commands like `\verb` still work as they are expected to?

Comment: You can't define commands with arguments inside the document; you can't use `&` as column separator in alignments; you can't use `~` as tie; no comment character available. No, thanks.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes the issues are mostly around external files, for example if `%` is not special you can go `\label{ab%c}` which means that you need `%` to be not special when the `.aux` file is read, which means that you need to make sure no package writes tex comments to the aux file....

Comment: @egreg In ConTeXt's ASCII mode `%%` is a comment: needs LuaTeX magic. That's why I asked about the target engine ...

Comment: @JosephWright: couldn't one use a macro, say `\C` for comments?

Comment: @egreg: ConTeXt doesnt use `&` as the column separator in any of the table mechanisms.

Comment: @Aditya The question is about LaTeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course vary the details of exactly what is redefined, and when but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\tablesep&

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@makeother\#%
\@makeother\$%
\@makeother\&%
\@makeother\%%
\@makeother\^%
\@makeother\_%
\@makeother\~%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\mycmd[2]{aaa(#1)(#2)}

\begin{document}

one # $ & ^ _ ~ two

\(x\sp{2}\)  

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
aaa \tablesep bbb \\
1 \tablesep 2
\end{tabular}

\verb| \{^} |

\mycmd{$$$}{%%%}



\end{document}
```

Comment: IIRC, ConTeXt changes the catcodes in math mode (using everymath, I believe). So, ^ and _ work in math mode.

Comment: @Aditya well that's easy enough to do as well of course (I wouldn't change catcodes though it wouldn't work inside macros, but simply make ^ be active and let to a ^ in text and \sp in math

Comment: ConTeXt goes out of the way to avoid active characters. I don't understand the TeX internals well enough, but I remember that lot of the "bugs" reported in the context mailing list in pdftex days (related to utf encoding) were due to active characters.